# img-square the same way img-circle works in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, image, css, thumbnails

I'm creating a portfolio in bootstrap with the class of thumbnails in a row and instead of making every thumbnail image square in Photoshop id like to just use a class like img-circle to make the thumbnails square before the viewer clicks on it to show the whole image.

Is this possible with just css no plugins?

Answer (score 1):

All that the bootstrap circle css does is add a border-radius to an element. It doesn't crop or centre an over sized image.

This is probably the easiest way to to crop and centre in a square container though I'd argue that you should be using a background image for this:

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aAQfk/2/)

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://your/large/image/source.jpg">
</div>
```

---

```
.thumbnail {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    bottom: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
    right: -9999px;
    margin: auto;
}
```